# Grep contents between delimiters <Directory /> and </Directory> from httpd.conf file

Tags: regex

How do I grep from the command line the contents between the delimiters  and  from the httpd.conf in Linux? I want to list the delimiters as well.

Comment: What is the regex engine / language / implementation you are working with? Without more details of your specification, this question is too broad. Please take a [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that trivially using *range patterns* in `awk`, like this:

```
awk '/<Directory/,/<\/Directory/' httpd.conf
```

i.e. the general syntax in an `awk` script are lines of the form

> *pattern* *{ action }*

where *pattern* in your case would be the range pattern */start/,/stop/* that matches beginning with a line that matches *start* until (and including) a line matching *stop*, and the default *action* is just to print the input.